# Obtain List of Losses Per Epoch from FastAI Learner

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, fast-ai

Is there a FastAI method for obtaining a list of losses during testing/validation?
I would like to obtain a list of numerical losses per epoch.

```
from fastai.text.all import *
learn = Learner(dls, model.cuda(), loss_func=nn.CrossEntropyLoss(), metrics=[accuracy])
EPOCHS = 250
OPTIMAL_LEARNING_RATE = 9.120108734350652e-05

learn.fit_one_cycle(EPOCHS, OPTIMAL_LEARNING_RATE)
```